# Sending Users to a site with iBeacons

Tags: swift, ibeacon, virtual-tour

I'm trying to create a virtual tour using iBeacons and one of the components I want is to send users to a video depending on which of the 3 ibeacons they are closest to using swift in Xcode.

I know you can use one beacon to send users to a specific youtube link but how would you do it if there are multiple beacons in a small area.

If anyone could help me out or even link resources that would help me out it would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: you need to give more information. you would essentially use different UUIDs for the beacon and match a link to an ID of a beacon.

Comment: you need to give more information. you would essentially use different UUIDs for the beacon and match a link to an ID of a beacon.